# Javascript - inherit parent function from different js file

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am running into an issue with inheritance in Javascript.

Child function inheriting parent function through prototype works when I have both parent and child functions in same js file.

Parent function:

```
var BaseFunction = function  (params) {    
}
```

Child function:

```
ChildFunction.prototype = new BaseFunction();
ChildFunction.prototype.constructor = ChildFunction;

var ChildFunction = function (params) {
    BaseFunction.call(this, params);
}
```

If I move all the child related code to a different js file, it is complaining BaseFunction is not defined. So, I changed it to below. Now, it is ending up as undefined.

```
ChildFunction.prototype = new window['BaseFunction']();
```

Wondering if inheriting a function from another file is possible? Greatly appreciate if you can share an example or point me to some article online.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, inheriting a function from another file is possible.  Can you post your `<script>` tags and make sure that you are loading the file with `BaseFunction` first?

Comment: Thanks go-oleg! I changed the order of my script files and it fixed the issue.